# How to assign scheduled tasks to a specific thread?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

Collegues, I have a group of tasks that are scheduled. In spring-boot properties file it looks like:

```
group1.task1.run = <execute every first minute>
group1.task2.run = <execute every second minute>


group2.task1.run = <execute every first minute>
group2.task2.run = <execute every second minute>
```

Is it possible to create two different threads (`T1` and `T2`) and assign the first group of scheduled tasks to be executed in `T1` thread, and the second group in `T2` thread?

I can’t just increase `PoolSize` in `TaskScheduler` beacuse after that `group1` tasks will be execute in different threads, it is not suitable for business process.

I would be grateful for any advice and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to specify a single thread. However, you can specify the `Executor` which should be used to schedule your tasks. If you wan't your tasks to be executed in the same thread, just create a thread pool with a single thread in it, like so:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class TempConfig {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    @Async(value = "threadPool1")
    public void task1() {
        System.out.println("Task1: " + Thread.currentThread());
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    @Async(value = "threadPool2")
    public void task2() {
        System.out.println("Task2: " + Thread.currentThread());
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor threadPool1() {
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor threadPool2() {
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    }
}
```

Of course, you can alternatively just schedule the tasks yourself:

```java
var s1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
var s2 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

// schedule tasks of group1
s1.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...);
s1.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...);

// schedule tasks of group2
s2.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...);
s2.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...);
```